# inject-dart Failed to snapshot build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart. This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-build, build-runner

I was trying to use [inject-dart](https://github.com/google/inject.dart) from Google by following [this article](https://blog.usejournal.com/compile-time-dependency-injection-in-flutter-95bb190b4a71)

But when I try to generate the code with build-runner but I see this error.

> [SEVERE] Failed to snapshot build script
>   .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart. This is likely caused by a
>   misconfigured builder definition. [SEVERE]
>   ../../../../dev/flutter/.pub-cache/git/inject.dart-4ffd3d339d8b776b2bec8d95ae6d3d168856e76c/package/inject_generator/lib/src/context.dart:106:51:
>   Error: Method not found: 'ParsedLibraryResultImpl.tmp'.      var
>   parsedLibrary = ParsedLibraryResultImpl.tmp(element.library);
>   ^^^

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 11):

use `element.library.session.getParsedLibraryByElement(element.library);`

instead of `ParsedLibraryResultImpl.tmp(element.library);` in Context.dart line 106

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error lately, @Mary answer helped me.

Just change the Context.dart line that is causing the headache to:

```
element.library.session.getParsedLibraryByElement(element.library);
```